# Can't call a method from a swift class in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm working on an iOS application written in Objective C that has an attached class written in Swift. When I try to call a in my Obj C AppDelegate.m, I don't get any errors, but the reply callback never fires.

My ObjC has the following methods:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void(^)(NSDictionary *replyInfo))reply {

    NSString *success =[ApiController handleCall];
    //NSString *success =[self hello]; // This works if you swap it with the above method 
    //NSString *success = @"hello";    // when uncommented this also works.

    NSDictionary *dict = @{@"status" : success};

    reply(dict);
}

-(NSString *)hello{
    return @"hello";
}
```

`NSString *success = [SwiftClass swiftMethod];`

My swift class looks like this:

```
@objc class SwiftClass {
    @objc func swiftMethod()->NSString{
        return "it works!"
    }
}
```

In addition to the above code, I've made sure to include `#import "ProjectName-Swift.h"`, as well as create a bridging header for the swift code.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Your code isn't clear - Is your invocation of `swiftMethod` actually inside a method?  Are you calling it on an instance of `SwiftClass` or are you literally calling `[SwiftClass swiftMethod]`?  The latter won't work because `swiftMethod` isn't a type method.

Comment: "I don't get any errors, but code just." ???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `swiftMethod` is an **instance** method not a **class** method. You can call it like this:

```
NSString *success = [[SwiftClass new] swiftMethod];
```

If you want to call it as class method then you need to declare it with `class`:

```
@objc class SwiftClass {
    @objc class func swiftMethod()->NSString{
        return "it works!"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you have to add `@objc` before class and method

```
@objc class MyClass: NSObjec {
   @objc func methodName() {
   }
}
```